# Ionic 3 getting error - Native: tried calling HTTP.setSSLCertMode, but the HTTP plugin is not installed

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I want to implement ssl pinning in my ionic 3 app. I have installed the @ionic/native http plugin using the following link - https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/http/

After everything has been setup when I try to run the app it shows the following error -

**Native: tried calling HTTP.setSSLCertMode, but the HTTP plugin is not installed.
Install the HTTP plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http'**

I have tried every possible solution available online but still I am not able to get this working.

I have tried moving the code inside platform ready function, the plugin references seem fine, I have tried cleaning and then npm install, still no luck.

What is going wrong here?
Help is really appreciated as I am scratching my head now!!

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE

```
this.http.setSSLCertMode("pinned")
.then((res) => {console.log(res)})
.catch((err) => {console.log(err)});
this.http.get("url", {},{})
.then((data) => {console.log(data)})
.catch((err) => {console.log(err)});
```

This is my code. If I remove the setSSLCetMode part in the code then the error goes away and the GET request is made.

Why is such behaviour happening?

Comment: So you also run this command? `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http`

Comment: Yes I have added this command before @ionic/native http

Comment: please check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try removing whatever platform you are generating a build for a adding it back. The plugin may be installed from your package.json for your project, but not for the specific platform you are using:

```
ionic cordova platform rm <insert platform here>
```

then

```
ionic cordova platform add <insert platform here>
```

after that rebuild your project. It seems pretty clear that it doesn't think you have that specific plugin installed so it has to be related to that in some way even indirectly. It could also be that you need to update the plugin as well.

Comment: I have tried removing and adding back the platform but it doesn't help
I have updated my question, If I remove the this.http.setSSLCertMode line, the plugin is detected and the request is made.